# Vertica Jdbc driver NOT throwing - SQL state: 22001 when ERROR: value too long for type

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, vertica

I have an issue I'm facing with Vertica JDBC Driver 
I try to store data into my DB - but sometimes the data isn't stored at all and I don't get any error its appear to be succeeded. it also happens when I try to use a file.

This seems to be a major bug - which against the 4 pillar of Data managment.
sample code is attached.

How can I solve this?

```
public class VerticaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("com.vertica.jdbc.Driver");
        String tableName = "vertica_test1";
        java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:vertica://xyz.qwe.com:5433/DB?tcpKeepAlive=true", "user", "admin");
        java.sql.Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        st.execute("Create table " + tableName + " (test_name varchar(10))");
        st.execute("grant all on " + tableName + " to public ");
        String value = "short";
        if (true) {
            value = "543543543 Sun Aug 11 065650 UTC 207657657650";
        }
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String copy = "COPY " + tableName + " FROM stdin  WITH parser LibCSVParser() abort on error no commit";
        VerticaCopyStream vcs = new VerticaCopyStream((VerticaConnection) connection, copy);
        vcs.start();
        vcs.addStream(stream);
        System.out.println("Reject size ROW IS " + vcs.getRejects().size());
        vcs.execute();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT count(1) FROM " + tableName);
        while (rs.next()) {
            int count = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("result = " + count);
        }
        rs.close();
        // st.execute("drop table " + tableName);
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Vertica copy statement doesn't behave like a traditional SQL INSERT statement. COPY doesn't fail, but reports rows that couldn't be inserted.

That's wise : let's say you want to insert 10 millions rows, you may not want it to fail fail because a single line is invalid.

To deal with the insertion errors, you have several options :

- the ["ABORT ON ERROR" parameter](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPY.htm) allows you to fail the whole COPY command as soon as one error occurs
- With Java, I tend to use the INSERT prepared statement (which behind the scenes uses COPY), as [documented here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/ClientJDBC/BatchInsertsUsingJDBCPreparedStatements.htm%3FTocPath%3DProgrammer%27s%2520Guide%7CHP%2520Vertica%2520Client%2520Libraries%7CProgramming%2520JDBC%2520Client%2520Applications%7CLoading%2520Data%2520Through%2520JDBC%7CBatch%2520Inserts%2520Using%2520JDBC%2520Prepared%2520Statements%7C_____0). The PreparedStatement.executeBatch(); returns an array of int representing the success/failure of each processed row.
- other strategies to deal with COPY errors are [documented here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/CapturingLoadExceptionsAndRejections.htm).

Comment: What if i need to load a file and not a line at a time ?
i original scenario is with a large file. a single value is just to demonstrate it

Comment: The same mechanisme is available when bulk loading a large file. You can output failures to a table or to a file, as described here : https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/CapturingLoadExceptionsAndRejections.htm

Comment: PreparedStatement.executeBatch() return boolean from what i see - not an array .

regardless to that 
even loading with

COPY vertica_test214122  FROM LOCAL 'c:\\Geo Sql\\bla_bla.csv'

Doesn't throw an error - isn't there a way to get an exception?

I really mean it - an exception is not that bad.
I don't want to count rows to find out if my DDL/ Copy command succeeded.

Comment: Did you try the "ABORT ON ERROR" copy parameter ? As pointed out, since it will fail on the first error, it may translate into a JAVA exception.

Comment: Yes I did , it's not throwing errors as I would want to.